# File Downloads To Browser

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, download

I have been working on creating a series of buttons that uploads, downloads, and deletes files in Spring MVC, with JSP pages, and Java this past few days.  I have the Upload and Delete working perfectly, and just got the download almost working.  I stress almost because the download comes with a very odd condition.

If I upload say an exe or a jar file, and then go back and try and download it. A box will show up asking me if I want to open it or save it.  If I want to do either it's not corrupted or anything, it's just fine.

If, however, the file is text based, as in a PDF, TXT, .doc, even XML, a browser tab will open, and it will show up in there.

So can anyone point me in the direction on how I might fix this?

The first block of code is my controller method, the second is the line in my jsp that triggers the button.

```
@RequestMapping("/FileDownload")
public ModelAndView FileDownload(
        @RequestParam(value = "FileID", required = false) int fileID,
        @RequestParam(value = "theFile", required = false) MultipartFile thefile,
        @ModelAttribute("fileAttachment") @Valid fileAttachment, BindingResult result, HttpServletResponse response){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        fileAttachment doc = attachmentService.getFileAttachment(fileID);
        try {
        response.setHeader("Content-   Disposition", "inline;filename=\""
                    + doc.getFileName() + "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType(doc.getFileType());
        FileCopyUtils.copy(doc.getFileContent(), response.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Here is the line that configures the button in the jsp

```
         <button name="FileDownloadd" type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=FileDownload.html?FileID=${fileattach.FileID}'">Download</button> </td>
```

Comment: `"Content-   Disposition"` Why do you have white space in your content-disposition header?

Comment: you're telling the browser to display it `inline`. That means if the browser knows how to render the file's contents, it will. text/pdf/xml can be rendered directly by a browser (or at least via a plugin). If you want to force a download, then use `attachment ` as your disposition, and/or force a mime-type like `application/octet-stream`, which the browser WON'T try to render.

Comment: I don't think there was whitespace, I think that happened when I pasted it over. 

Testing Marc's comment now.

Comment: That worked, how do I mark a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Marc's comment above was the answer. Since it was a comment, and I want to close this. I will post it in quotes.

> you're telling the browser to display it inline. That means if the browser >knows how to render the file's contents, it will. text/pdf/xml can be rendered >directly by a browser (or at least via a plugin). If you want to force a >download, then use attachment  as your disposition, and/or force a mime-type >like application/octet-stream, which the browser WON'T try to render.